# Anomalies and determinant bundle curvature

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, quantum-anomalies

I heard that anomalies and curvature of [determinant bundle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/determinant+line+bundle) are related. Namely, curvature of determinant bundle is related to Chern-Simons form (which are involved in description of gauge anomalies).

I know about Chern-Simons forms and anomalies, but I have no knowledge about determinant bundle and its relationship with anomalies.

Do you know any literature that would be helpful for understanding it (not very mathematical).

Answer (score 4):

A standard reference packed to the brim with other references to everything you ever wanted to know about anomalies is *"Anomalies in Quantum Field Theory"* by Bertlmann. This particular topic is what comprises part of chapter 11 there. I'll highlight the main points, but this *is* a technical topic for which you'll have to go to the references and follow all of the numerous steps in the derivations to understand them:

The relation between a gauge anomaly and a determinant bundle arises once you realize that the gauge anomaly term can be computed by a certain determinant, for instance following the method of Fujikawa. This particular construction is due to Alvarez-Gaumé and Ginsparg. One defines a "square root" $\hat{D}$ of the Dirac operator $D$ as
$$ \hat{D} = \gamma^\mu \left(\partial_\mu + A_\mu P_+\right)$$
where $P_+$ projects onto positive chirality fermions. The partition function of a Dirac fermion $\psi$ with action $\int\bar\psi\mathrm{i}\hat{D}\psi$ is given by the functional determinant of $\mathrm{i}D$. Anomalousness of the path integral measure under a gauge transformation means non-invariance of this determinant, and allows one to compute the anomaly due to a positive chirality Weyl fermion.

The relevant determinant bundle lives on a subspace (a two-sphere, to be precise) of the space of connections $\mathcal{A}$ modulo gauge transformations that vanish at infinity $\mathcal{G}_0$. If the determinant of $\hat{D}$, which is a functional of $A$, is gauge-variant, then it cannot be a well-defined global function on $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{G}_0$ - the presence of an anomaly is thus detected by this determinant bundle being non-trivial, i.e. lacking global sections.

Comment: Thank you, it helps a lot. I am currently reading Bertlmann's "Anomalies...", but haven't get to 11 chapter yet.